# byte[] array in Java(size declaration)

Tags: java, arrays

I have declared 3 different types of byte arrays(of different sizes). See the comment next to each as I am not able to understand how the `length` is computed by the compiler?

```
    byte[] byteField0 = new byte[2^3];
    System.out.println("bitField0 " + byteField0.length); // Gives 1 byte instead of 8?
    byte[] byteField2 = new byte[2^5];
    System.out.println("byteField2 " + byteField2.length); // Gives 7 bytes instead of 32?
    byte[] byteField3 = new byte[8];
    System.out.println("bitField3: " + byteField3.length); // Gives 8 bytes as expected
```

Comment: `^` is the exclusive-or operator (xor).

Comment: You want to use `<<` to left-shift to get powers of 2: `1 << 3` is 8, `1 << 5` is 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with array size. Print those numbers individually, or more importantly, as binary.

`^` is XOR bitwise operator, not a replacement for `Math.pow`

Or as mentioned in comments, powers of two can be accomplished with a different bitwise operator, the left shift `<<`, which would be computationally faster than `Math.pow`